# Define a value of type Tree corresponding to the diagram

Tags: haskell

following this definition of tree data type

```
 data Tree = Leaf Int | Node Int Tree Tree
```

Define a value of type Tree that corresponds to the diagram

```
       0
    1    2
 3   4   5  6
```

t : tree

t =

I'm somewhat confused about the constructor leaf vs node. and The exact structure the question is asking. So there is a constructor Node that creates a node with 2 tree branches and one that just creates a single leaf node correct? does that mean in our definition that the only time 'leaf' is used is at the end and to call node at the beginning?

```
t = Node '0' 
    (Node '1'
       (leaf '3')
       (leaf '4')
     )
    (Node '2'
       (leaf '5')
       (leaf '6')
     )
```

typing this out kind of helped me rationalize this ha. Is what I have correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `0` instead of `'0'` (because the type in the definition is `Int` and `'0'` doesn't denote an `Int`) and `Leaf` instead of `leaf`. Otherwise correct.